# Zeppelin doesn't find ZEPPELIN_PID_DIR

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Just cloned Zeppelin from https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin, Ran `mvn clean package -DskipTests -Pspark-1.6 -Phadoop-2.4 -Pyarn -Ppyspark`, I've configured the `zeppelin-env.sh`.

Still, when running `zeppelin.sh` I get:

```
Pid dir doesn't exist, create 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
```

When I launch localhost:8080, I see a blank page. Anyone knows what's up with that?

Comment: pid dir in zeppelin using ZEPPELIN_PID_DIR="${ZEPPELIN_HOME}/run", you can try creating your own `run` folder inside the zeppelin root directory.